# Azure Data Factory - LiveCodeBackup

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-data-factory, azure-devops-rest-api

I have 150 pipelines and many datasets defined in Azure data factory. I want to take backup of live code everyday and save it to the code repository.
What is the best approach to backup the Code/pipelines/datasets/linked services to GIT repository. Do we have any API's available for the task?
Can we achieve this with PowerShell code? if yes, please share the PS code if you have it handy.
Appreciate your help..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Set up a code repository*** in the ***Azure data factory***, then you can save all your resources to ***Azure DevOps*** or ***GitHub*** and get the ***Backup***.

Please follow the below ***reference*** it has detailed expiation of ***GitHub code repository setup*** and ***Restores***, ***backup*** of ***Azure data factory.***

You can use another way to take [***Backup and Restore Azure Data Factory***](https://www.techbrothersit.com/2021/10/copy-or-clone-data-factory-in-azure.html) using an ***ARM template.***

[image: Ref1]
[image: Ref2]

**Reference:**

https://www.sqlshack.com/using-source-control-in-azure-data-factory/

[How to Backup and Restore Azure Data Factory from ARM Template ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEprrAK7eM8)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5uMYO06aMI

[How to Backup and Restore Azure DevOps code repositories ?](https://gaikovoi.medium.com/how-to-backup-azure-devops-code-repositories-5c6fb4274c04)